# Would support question be on topic

Tags: discussion, on-topic

[Another from the proposal](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14537/would-support-questions-be-on-topic) by [Styphon](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/106199/styphon) for discussion

One question I thought of posting was

> what techniques can I use to stay sane whilst building my world?

But then I started thinking, is this about world building? Would such a question be considered on topic? Will this site cater for questions that are not directly about building a world, but more about the people building the world's and any queries they may have during the process of building a world?

Comment: I suggest the `[on-topic]` tag for this question.

Answer (score 11):

I think that that with a rewording, the original intent of the question could remain while the answers would be more appropriate. Just off the top of my head:

> What techniques can be used to keep track of complex interactions between cultures in a world?
>
> How do you organize your design so that you can keep track of what has been worked on?

These examples, instead of going "my head hurts", instead focus on methods and practices used in designing and building worlds, while giving the same kind of answer. Its about asking the question with the worldbuilding being the focus, rather than the worldbuilder.

Comment by [Bobson](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/74216/bobson)

Going off of this, I'd say the OP's question would be closed as "Too vauge", and then the clarity of why his project is giving a headache (such as your examples) would lead to it reopening.

Answer (score 5):

A question like "what techniques can I use to stay sane whilst building my world?" is **incredibly broad.** Stay sane in what regard? Without more context, that's the sort of question that, at the very least, needs not a world-building expert but **a doctor or a psychiatrist to be answered,** and the answer is likely to be heavily tailored toward the asker and as such unlikely to be useful to any future visitors. That makes the question a poor fit for the Stack Exchange model of Q&A.

Such a question should in my opinion be closed most likely as **"too broad" or "primarily opinion-based",** depending on specifics.

However, if the question can be posed in terms of something answerable, which relates to the process of world-building, *then* it would be on topic. Questions about how to arrange materials, keep track of the history of your world, and so on, have the specificity that the original question does not, and as such may very well be on topic (subject to other requirements). But your example has no information on which to base such a rewrite, which would essentially involve rewriting the entire question, so any edits to that effect would be pure guesswork. Such edits should likely be rejected, perhaps as "radical change".